# Backslash-single quote \'

Tags: javascript

My question regarding the \'add \' backslash-single quote that being passed into the method validate, what is the use of that backslash-single code?

```
document.writeln('<td width="12%"><INPUT name=btnAdd type=button value="Add" align="right" onclick="if(Validate(this.form,\'add\',\'<%=i%>\',\'N\'))></td>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Backslash tells the code that this isn't a part of qoutation, it instead is a text character. 
And it is known as escape character which is used to escape the code start and ending points.
For example:

```
alert("Hi, " is a double qoute");
```

won't work, since the qoutation of the string has been ended! Might provide an exception if environment throws one. While this one:

```
alert("Hi, \" is a double qoute");
```

Won't show up any error. And you will get the written text as the alert popup. You can even see the difference in the Stack Overflow code viewer.

Your code:

```
this.form,\'add\',\'<%=i%>\',\'N\')
```

Will be executed as:

```
this.form, 'add', '<%=i%>, 'N'
```

And you will get the value as needed!

Comment: i see... so it still actually will pass (this.form, 'add' , '<%=i%>', 'N') to the validate method right?

Comment: Here the function will execute perfectly as it has to, since there is no `\` in the code. What you tried to do ??

Comment: im trying to pass 4 values into validate method.

function validate(FORM,TYPE,NumRe,ManChk)
{

}

Comment: sorry i quite not get it, because i thought when you need to pass value into the method, need to put single-quote, and with the backslash it will actually pass 'add', '<%=i%>', 'N' into validate method...For example:

<button onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">Try it</button>

Comment: No, once you start the string as `'hi...` you end it up with `..'` any type of `"` will be considered as a qoutation rather than ending string .. So, strings starting with single qoutes end up with single qoutes! :) Back slashes are used to prevent such events..in a strings starting from `'` will end up at `'` but if you add `\'` string won't end up, but will continue until the next single qoute..

Answer (score 2):

It is called `escape character`. It escapes the special meaning of the next character.

Here it depresses the power of the quote. Usually used to nest the quotes in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

If you are confusing with that one,then change it as

```
document.writeln("<td width='12%'><INPUT name=btnAdd type=button value='Add' align='right' onclick='if(Validate(this.form,\'add\',\'<%=i%>\',\'N\'))></td>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash () is an escape character in Javascript (along with a lot of other C-like languages). This means that when Javascript encounters a backslash, it tries to escape the following character. For instance, \n is a newline character (rather than a backslash followed by the letter n).

And This kind of string '/\S+@\S+.\S+/' is called Reg-ex. Regular expressions are used to perform powerful pattern-matching and "search-and-replace" functions on text.basically it is used for validation.